Raft algorithm three nodes scenario
When a cluster has three nodes, then one of them is down. According to rule, it can tolerate one node fail. But there are two node left, one is leader, the other is follower, how can leader get majority vote during Leader Election? Can a leader vote for itself? The leader waits until a majority of nodes have written the entry, so in this situation, how does leader can get majority?
If leader can vote for itself, but in Log Replication, need wait forever to get two followers to response.

You are right: nodes do vote for themselves when they become candidates. Please, see page 4 in https://raft.github.io/raft.pdf (the candidate section).
When a leader is down in a three nodes clusters, these steps will happend:

each remaining follower won't receive heartbeat
with some jitter, a follower flips to a candidate step
the candidate sends RequestVote to other two nodes (with only one of those nodes being available)
if the candidate has their log at least as updates as the other node, the other node would grant the vote
the candidate has two votes now: from itself and from the other node - this is the majority and the candidate may behave as a leader

Two edge cases:

it is possible that the candidate's log is behind; then this candidate won't get the other vote
it is possible that two remaining nodes become candidates at the same time - so the both have a single vote (from themselves) and are not able to get another vote for the same term

In either of above cases, a new election round happens. And there is a randomization when a follower flips to a candidate state to resolve the tie.
